# How can i solve this problem: Java Android after fragment destroy, running background

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

I am coding an android mobile application with java programming language. I provide fragment transitions on an Activity. But for example, if I make Status:1 in fragment A, sometimes fragment B runs in the background and makes Status:2. This is why my flow is not working correctly. How can I solve this problem? Somehow the Fragment does not get destroyed or it restarts on its own.

Here is onDestroy() method:

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        super.onDestroy();
        super.onDetach();
        Logging.Info("Test ProcessCancelFragment-onDestroyView 8");
    }
```

Here is navigation fragment transaction:

```
private void GoToComplete(View view) {
        try {
            ConstantsAlertSettings();
            NavDirections action = ProcessCancelFragmentDirections.actionProcessCancelFragmentToAlertInfoFragment();
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logging.Error("ProcessCancelFragment-onTimeout Try-Catch Message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show as some code

Comment: @fascynacja i was edited this post.